# NodeJS backend POST for array item?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Sample JSON data, to show you how my MongoDB is arranged:

```
{
"state" : "California"
"person" [{"name": "Bob"}, {"name": "Bill"}]
}
```

I have an input form with the following POST value `name` and `state` in my HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="state" />
<input type="text" name="name"/>
```

Now, in order to process this POST, I have my Node route code arranged like so:

```
router.post('/profile', function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id }, function(err, user) {

    if (err) return next(err);
    /*first action*/ 
    user.state = req.body.state;
    /*second action*/
    user.person.name = req.body.name; 

    user.save(function(err) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      req.flash('success', 'Purchase successful');
      return res.redirect('/profile');
    });
  });
});
```

Here is what's meant to happen. First, upon input and submission of `state`, the state (as shown in my DB) will change to whatever the user has typed. This works as intended.

Second, upon input and submission of `name`, there should be a new `name` added to the array.

The second action does not work. I have tried replacing the code with a push and for loop, like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < user.person.length; i++){
user.push({
    name: person[i].name
});
}
```

This has not worked. I would also like to add that this is all meant to be rendered via ejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 user.person.push({"name":req.body.name});
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, `user.person` is an array - so you cannot access `name` like `user.person.name`  -if you want to add a new name, then you need to access the `person` array and then push the new `req.body.name` - is this what you intend to do? In that case - this is what you should do:

```
//the rest of your code...
if (err) return next(err);
    /*first action*/ 
    user.state = req.body.state;
    /*second action*/
    //Here you PUSH the new name into this array
    user.person.push({'name':req.body.name}); 

    user.save(function(err) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      req.flash('success', 'Purchase successful');
      return res.redirect('/profile');
    });
//---the rest of your code
```

Give it a try and let me know if this helps.